# Identity Server Middleware ASP NET core pages styles

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I'm using the ASP .Net Core Identity Server to authenticate users in my application (I used the default actual Visual Studio template including Angular + Integrated Authentication with Identity).

Everything is working well in Development mode but I have one problem when I deploy it to IIS. The IdentityServer is supposed to provide some js and css files to show the default login, register etc... pages but the give result when this file is asked is the angular application so html content...

Any idea ?

NB : I tried to change the environment name to Testing in my debug mode, and I have the same result : no js and css provided. It's like if Identity did not register the provider in Development mode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default login and register pages provided by Default identity ui, not by Identity server. (AddDefaultIdentity or AddDefaultUI)

Maybe you have problem with production certificate (to use for signing tokens)?